# Jquery changing an event

Tags: jquery, html

So basically, I am facing a problem.

I have a series of popable divs (that drop down), and they have a "close" button inside them, in a normal view, this triggers the popable divs to close.

I have changed the functionality, in that, inside certain divs, there is a link which transitions to another div, this works fine.

The problem:

I want the functionality of the "X" button to change, depending on the state of where the user is at, so basically changing the event listener. So that, if the user is in a standard pop out div, click "X" the div is closed. If the user has transitioned into another div from the main one, then it should just go back to the main div once they have clicked on the "X" button.

Currently, I have tried the following, and it works, but after the first time, everytime you click the "X" an alert pops up. (I only, for now, want the alert to come up in the secondary divs).

```
 $('.grantsPage').click(function()
    {
        $('.X').bind("click", function(){

            alert("Clicked");
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $(".subContentDiv").slideUp();
        $("#divemployers-grants").slideDown().addClass('active');
        scrollToSubSection('id3');
        e.preventDefault();

    });
```

Any ideas to where I am going wrong?

Comment: `on` and `off` are preferable to `bind/unbind` with later versions of jQuery. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Adding click handlers nested inside click handlers is normally a sign of problems. Separate them and instead check if the div open/closed state in the handler. Please show some appropriate HTML so we can provide an appropriate example (e.g. save part of the DOM from the Chrome F12 DOM inspector) :)

Comment: If the first `e` goes with `X`, and the second goes with `grantsPage`, you'll need to add `e` as a parameter to each function.

Comment: @RickHitchcock How do you mean>

Comment: Change each `function()` to `function(e)`.  Otherwise, `e` is undefined (unless it's defined elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

I think `unbind` can do the trick:

```
$('.grantsPage').click(function() {
    $('.X').bind("click", function(){

        alert("Clicked");
        $('.X').unbind();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(".subContentDiv").slideUp();
    $("#divemployers-grants").slideDown().addClass('active');
    scrollToSubSection('id3');
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I unbind there, then when it returns to the normal div.. It is not getting re-binded so therefore the functionality just stops?

Comment: Yes, I tried this. It's working, but when you unbind this event then you unbind it for the whole element, it never get's rebinded. I can't show you the HTML as it's quite a large site